# How to display the results of type "Schema.DescribeSObjectResult" in visualforce page....?

Tags: visualforce

I just want to display the fields and other details of selected sobject in the picklist on visulforce page.
And i got the all sobjects of my org....but how to display the result of type Schema.DescribeSObjectResult on the visualforce page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code as sample reference

```
<apex:page controller="objectList" >
  <apex:form >
<apex:SelectList value="{!val}" size="1">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:SelectList>
```

The apex class

```
public class objectList{
public String val {get;set;}

 public List<SelectOption> getName(){
  List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();     
  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
  {
    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
 }
 return options;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply Mr. Mohit Shrivastava.............but it is not the problem, i got all the sobjects into the picklist....i want to display each sobject details on visulforce page when i picked an item from that picklist......My main question is i got the result in type of Schema.DescribeSObjectResult in cotroller how to display it on the visualforce page....?

Comment: are you using multipicklist or kindly ellaborate what details you want to display on the page about object ?

Answer (score 1):

You can display the "get" method values of the of [DescribeSObjectResult](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) quite simply by just dropping the "get" from the name:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!describes}" var="d">
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!d.name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Label" value="{!d.label}"/>
    ...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

where `describes` is a list of the DescribeSObjectResult objects.

However, the "is" fields are not supported in this way so you will have to use a wrapper:

```
public class DescribeWrapper {
    public DescribeSObjectResult d {get; private set;}
    public DescribeWrapper(DescribeSObjectResult d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
    public Boolean getAccessible() {
        return d.isAcessible();
    }
    ...
}
```

and return a list of those from your controller so you can then reference either the underlying DescribeSObjectResult properties or the wrapper properties:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!describes}" var="d">
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!d.d.name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Label" value="{!d.d.label}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Accessible" value="{!d.accessible}"/>
    ...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

If you have the willpower, wrapping all the methods would make the Visualforce look better.